# MvvmCross - On View Loaded Event in Android

Tags: android, wpf, xamarin, mvvmcross

When using MvvmCross with a WPF app, you can get the ViewModel in the View, once the "Loaded" event has occurred.

Is there an equivalent in Android?

```
public partial class DashboardView
{
    public DashboardView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // until loaded, we can not access viewmodel
        Loaded += (sender, args) =>
        {
            var viewModel = (DashboardViewModel)ViewModel;
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ViewModel for MvxView is populated by MvvmCross for you.  For Wpf it happens [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Wpf/Views/MvxWpfViewsContainer.cs#L40).  The same applies for Android.  You'll have access to the ViewModel in OnCreate().

If you inherit your view from `MvxWpfView<MyViewModel>`, you won't need the cast.

So you can access with a property or however...

```
public LoginViewModel LoginViewModel
        {
            get { return (LoginViewModel)ViewModel; }
        }
```

Comment: There's also lots of reasonably good docs on Android lifecycle - see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: I figured it would be more complicated, like the WPF where you have to wait for the load to complete. Thanks for the help!